# SwiftUI: Make inset List background transparent?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

How would I set the gray background of the `List` to be fully transparent to let the red come through?

[image: gray]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Faux Title")
                            .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // settings
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                                .font(.system(.title2))
                        })
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    
                    List {
                        Text("One")
                        Text("Two")
                        Text("Three")
                    }
                    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In init() of View changing `UITableView.appearance`:
The most things that we are using in SwiftUI such as List or NavigationView, . . they are not pure SwiftUI and they are coming from UIKit, therefore we use UIKit code type for changing appearance. if you remember we should use such codes in UIKit. And when we use `UITableView` in init we are accessing to the class of **UITableView** UIKit, it means this change would apply to any View in our project which they are using List.

The best way is the way you are doing, setting transparent Color, then changing Color from SwiftUI in body! that is the most convenient way.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() { UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear }   // <<: here!
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Faux Title")
                            .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // settings
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                                .font(.system(.title2))
                        })
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    
                    List {
                        Text("One")
                        Text("Two")
                        Text("Three")
                    }
                    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! This works! I wonder if you could update your answer with a brief explanation of why this works and what it's actually doing. Still trying to wrap my head around some of this SwiftUI stuff. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for that I explained it in up, it is not pure SwiftUI, that is why we should use some UIKit code as well.

Answer (score 2):

In **IOS 16** you can use:

```
List { 
  Text("test-item") 
}.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```